# How can i start a different simulator with Rubymotion command line

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

In [Rubymotion](http://www.rubymotion.com) we start terminal with `rake`

```
Ankits-MacBook-Pro:Magic ankitgupta$ rake 
     Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-6.0-Development
  Simulate ./build/iPhoneSimulator-6.0-Development/Magic.app
(main)>
```

By default it is starting `iPhoneSimulator-6.0-Development` . How can i start `iPhone 5.1` or `5.0 Simulator` ?

Comment: You can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279608/selecting-the-ios-simulator-device-type-with-rubymotion/26294916#26294916

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to set the target via the rake command, for example:

```
$ rake target=5.1 # => iOS 5.1
```

Noted in this pull request: https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotion/pull/10

Answer (score 2):

To change the target device and OS try this:

```
bundle exec rake target=8.4 device_name="iPad 2"
```